# Как перенести магазин с opencart версии 1.5 на 2.0.1?

Tags: opencart

Как перенести рабочий магазин на *opencart* 1.5 на версию 2.0.1?

У заказчика есть рабочий магазин на версии 1.5. Он купил шаблон, который работает с версии 2.0.1.

Уже пробовал сносить полностью старую версию, устанавливал тему (работает отлично), потом импортировал данные из *БД*. И все слетает, выдает кучу ошибок. Теоретически с нуля сделать проще, но очень много товаров и прочих данных.

Comment: У OcSotrе нет версии 2.0...

Answer (score 1):

[Google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=opencart%20upgrade%201.5%20to%202.0): opencart upgrade 1.5 to 2.0 - Результатов: примерно 70 200

Чаще лучше всего поднять с нуля новый магазин, а потом экспорт/импорт (плагинов много) данных из старого в новый.

Comment: Алексей, Гугл это хорошо, но если я обратился сюда это наверное значит, что я ничего не нашел?!

Comment: Собственно второй строкой я как раз предложил альтернативный вариант. Наиболее безболезненный вариант - перелить данные в новый магазин, без апгрейдов. На данный момент абсолютно не понятно текущее состояние, допиленность и перепиленность старого проекта и жизнеспособность темы для новой версии.

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой неоднократно, как показывает практика делаем полностью магазин с 0 на 2хх потом начинаем переносить категории товары в новый магазин.

Answer (score 0):

Я переносил товары с OcStore 1.5x на OpenCart 2.3.0.2
Я использовал [модуль Database Converter to OpenCart 2](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=20423) для конвертирования базы данных в 2+
После я установил ещё один движок OcStore версии 2.0 
После установки я поставил конвертированную базу данных.
Потом c устанавливаем [модуль экпорта / импорта в Excel](https://opencart.ws/export-import-excel-opencart.html) на наш новый магазин и магазин OcStore
Делаем экспорт на окстори в xls файл 
Потом делаем экспорт с нового сайта на OpenCart 
Сравниваем 2 таблицы и редактируете имена столбцов в прайсе с товарами.
Вот и всё... решение проблемы отняло у меня целый день.
Если вы знаете как решить данную проблему по другому пишите.
В работе использовал 3 движка OcStore 1.5 OcStore 2.0 | и конечный сайт OpenCart 2.3.0.2.
Если переносить с OC на OC то всё будет гораздо проще!